# How to mock data returned from MongoClient() in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, unit-testing, mocking, pymongo

I am trying to write test case, I want to mock data object returned from MongoClient(), below is the code.

**numbers.py**

```py
def get_count():

    client_int = MongoClient('abc.xyz.com', port=27010)

    return client_int
```

**test_numbers.py**

```py
@patch('pymongo.MongoClient')

def test_get_count(mocked_object):

    mocked_object.return_value = [{'1': 'data'}]

    assert numbers.get_count() == [{'1': 'data'}] # Here i am getting Assertion Error, MongoClient!=[{'1': 'data'}]
```

How to make this work?? What went wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should rename your module. You can't use `numbers`, because it conflicts with python built-in library [numbers](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/numbers.html).

You didn't patch the target correctly. You should patch `MongoClient` of `my_numbers.py` module. For more info, see [where-to-patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch)

E.g.

`my_numbers.py`:

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient


def get_count():

    client_int = MongoClient('abc.xyz.com', port=27010)

    return client_int
```

`test_my_numbers.py`:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
import my_numbers


class TestNumbers(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('my_numbers.MongoClient')
    def test_get_count(self, mocked_object):
        mocked_object.return_value = [{'1': 'data'}]
        assert my_numbers.get_count() == [{'1': 'data'}]
        mocked_object.called_once_with_value('abc.xyz.com', port=27010)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

unit test result:

```
 ⚡  coverage run /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/python-codelab/src/stackoverflow/66852436/test_my_numbers.py && coverage report -m --include='./src/**'
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
Name                                            Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/66852436/my_numbers.py            4      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/66852436/test_my_numbers.py      11      0   100%
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                              15      0   100%
```

Comment: Thanks, its perfect